# Enumerating Registry keys with it's data in C

Tags: c, registry, enumerate

I am still a beginner in C , I found a useful code in C whcih helped me getting a Key Values but i am Trying to print ("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion") with all it's values and data , but i can only get the Values without the Data , i would like to get both Values and it's data like  (ProductName :Windows 7 , SystemRoot : C:\Windows ,  etc ... )  , if someone can help me with this code i would be so grateful , i used "RegQueryValueEx" but it only gives me a specific data for a single value .

Thanks

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define MAX_KEY_LENGTH 255
#define MAX_VALUE_NAME 16383
void QueryKey(HKEY hKey)
{
    TCHAR   achKey[MAX_KEY_LENGTH];   // buffer for subkey name
    DWORD   cbName;                // size of name string
    TCHAR   achClass[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("");  // buffer for class name
    DWORD   cchClassName = MAX_PATH;  // size of class string
    DWORD   cSubKeys=0;            // number of subkeys
    DWORD   cbMaxSubKey;              // longest subkey size
    DWORD   cchMaxClass;              // longest class string
    DWORD   cValues;              // number of values for key
    DWORD   cchMaxValue;          // longest value name
    DWORD   cbMaxValueData;    // longest value data
    DWORD   cbSecurityDescriptor; // size of security descriptor
    FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;     // last write time
    DWORD i, retCode;
    TCHAR  achValue[MAX_VALUE_NAME];
    DWORD cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME;
    // Get the class name and the value count.
    retCode = RegQueryInfoKey(hKey,achClass,&cchClassName,NULL,&cSubKeys,&cbMaxSubKey,&cchMaxClass,&cValues,&cchMaxValue,&cbMaxValueData,&cbSecurityDescriptor,&ftLastWriteTime);
    // Enumerate the subkeys, until RegEnumKeyEx fails.
    if (cSubKeys)
    {
        printf( "\nNumber of subkeys: %d\n", cSubKeys);
        for (i=0; i<cSubKeys; i++)
        {
            cbName = MAX_KEY_LENGTH;retCode = RegEnumKeyEx(hKey, i,achKey,&cbName,NULL,NULL,NULL,&ftLastWriteTime);
            if (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                _tprintf(TEXT("(%d) %s\n"), i+1, achKey);
            }
        }
    }
    // Enumerate the key values.
    if (cValues)
    {
        printf( "\nNumber of values: %d\n", cValues);
        for (i=0, retCode=ERROR_SUCCESS; i<cValues; i++)
        {
            cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME;
            achValue[0] = '\0';
            retCode = RegEnumValue(hKey, i, achValue, &cchValue, NULL,  NULL, NULL, NULL);
            if (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS )
            {
                _tprintf(TEXT("(%d) %s\n"), i+1, achValue);
            }
        }
    }
}

void _tmain(void)
{
   HKEY hTestKey;
   if( RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
        TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion"),0, KEY_READ, &hTestKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS
      )

   {
      QueryKey(hTestKey);

   }
   RegCloseKey(hTestKey);
}
```

Comment: Spend some time learning what all those functions, and particular the parameters that seem like odd sequences of NULL, actually *do*. It may prove useful.

Comment: Actually i know most of the functions and i know how to get a single data from value with RegQueryValueEX function , but i just don't know how to get all the data instead of a single one with RegQueryValueEX

Answer (score 0):

why don't run command like REGEDIT -E thorugh c Program, through this you can easily export full value then read as normal file using file handling mechnism in C.
please follow link.

 http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000848.htm

Comment: Well , i want to know how to use RegQueryValueEX .